# Don't pair quotes in electric-pair-mode

Tags: quote, electric-pair-mode, pairing

How can I get `electric-pair-mode` to *not* pair quotation marks (single or double)? I still want it to pair everything else (brackets, braces, etc.), just not quotes.

Comment: Have you tried customizing `electric-pair-inhibit-predicate`?

Comment: @elethan where do I find this `electric-pair-inhibit-predicate` variable? It's unknown to my emacs 24.3.1

Comment: @ggll I am using Emacs 25.1.1 and for me it is in `elec-pair.el`.

Comment: In source of `electric-pair-mode`, `electric-pair-pairs` and `electric-pair-text-pairs` is used for customization, but `electric-pair-text-syntax-table` takes precedence. A hook that locally sets these variables should be enough to get this to work. I'll check if that's the case later and post an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following to your emacs init file:

```
(setq electric-pair-inhibit-predicate
      (lambda (c)
        (if (char-equal c ?\") t (electric-pair-default-inhibit c))))
```

Reference from my blog post: https://www.topbug.net/blog/2016/09/29/emacs-disable-certain-pairs-for-electric-pair-mode/

Comment: This does not work for me. Double quotes are still paired.

Comment: @Ben Which emacs version do you have. Please add that information to your question. Please, try the code from this answer with `emacs -Q` (emacs started with command line option `-Q`). Perhaps some other package interferes. The code works for me with GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.20) of 2017-09-11.

Comment: I'm adding an answer because I can't yet comment. @xuhdev has the answer right but for reasons I don't really understand in my system when I evaluate: (setq electric-pair-inhibit-predicate (lambda (c) (if (char-equal c ?\") t (electric-pair-default-inhibit c)))) I get (lambda (c) (if (char-equal c 34) t (electric-pair-default-inhibit c))). So try M-x customize-variable, choose electric-pair-inhibit-predicate, and then choose from the value-menu function and in the box write: (lambda (c) (if (char-equal c ?\") t (electric-pair-default-inhibit c))) This way it works for my configurations at emac

Comment: Please don't post a pseudo answer in lieu of a comment. When you gain a bit of "reputation" points you will be able to comment. If you're wondering why `?\"` ends up printed as `34`, it's because the `"` character is the same as the integer `34`. In Emacs, characters are positive integers of a certain range.

Comment: This must be an electric.el version problem. I am using `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) of 2016-01-13`.

Comment: Just confirmed that this answer _does_ work in 25.3.1. This answer will become more correct as older versions of emacs become obsolete, so I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Update: @xuhdev's answer is preferable as it doesn't interfere with Emacs' code.

Might be worth a feature request having that customizable. For the moment, it looks trivial to modify the code in question.

Afterwards load your own variant of electric-pair-post-self-insert-function

Open elec-pair.el and copy from there

```
(defun electric-pair-post-self-insert-function ()
[ ... ] )
```

Then look into the body for any

```
(memq syntax '(?\( ?\) ?\" ?\$))
```

and delete the `?\"` from there, i.e.

```
(memq syntax '(?\( ?\) ?\$))
```

but not delete ?\" at other places(!)

and reload i.e. evaluate the changed function.

To reload at next session put it into some file "my-changed-stuff.el" and load this from your init-file.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for emacs 24.3.1.

Comment: I couldn't find `electric-pair-post-self-insert-function`

Comment: @alper Needs loading the sources: electric-pair-post-self-insert-function is a compiled Lisp function in ‘elec-pair.el’.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you cannot. The various customizations only allow you to add pairs.

If you're willing to use a different package to do your pairing, you can try [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens). You can set quotation marks to not pair as follows:

```
(sp-pair "'" nil :actions :rem)
(sp-pair "\"" nil :actions :rem)
```

Comment: Note that smartparens lacks some subtle features from electric-pair that aren't immediately obvious. If you can get over that (or mod them in yourself) it may be worth switching anyway. Smartparents has other useful features and is a lot more flexible.

Comment: Could you mention a subtle electric-pair feature missing from smartparens, @JackCC?

Comment: It's been a while since I switched, so these might be wrong, but off the top of my head: if you have a closing brace immediately following the cursor (or with whitespace between it), typing the opening brace in `electric-pair` will respect the existing closing brace. In `smartparens`, a new closing brace is always created unless you are in strict mode (which has other strong side-effects). For example: `|)` -> `(|)` in `electric-pair` versus `|)` -> `(|))` in smartparens. The pipe symbol `|` represents the cursor.

Comment: Likewise, if you are in `electric-pair` and you have a closing brace four lines down with only whitespace between your cursor and the closing brace and you type that closing brace, it will replace the brace below, causing it to become flush with the cursor. That doesn't happen in `smartparens` unless you're in strict mode. This is a nice shortcut when editing something like lisp (or even something like Python, honestly) because it reduces the cognitive overhead of formatting s-expressions. It can make balancing braces more confusing though.

Comment: I believe `electric-pair` also inherits its pairs from the syntax table of the current mode, whereas in `smartparens` you have to explicitly program in every pair. I could be wrong about that one though.

Comment: Can I use `electric-pair` and `smartparens ` together?

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be simpler, based on @xuhdev's answer:

```
(setq electric-pair-inhibit-predicate (lambda (c) (char-equal c ?\")))
```

The doc says

> The function is called with a single char (the opening char just
> inserted). If it returns non-nil, then ‘electric-pair-mode’ will not
> insert a matching closer.

So the lambda only needs to return a boolean.